# show layer after mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i need to do something like this :
http://www.aparatfilimo.com/

when you go on pictures (mouse hover) a layer or something else will show. i tried popover using bootstrap, but the problem is, when i change show type to hover, it works like a tooltip and i cant let user go to the second layer (tooltip content) and click on the "read more" text on it.

so i need to know what is the best solution to create this.

here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html:true , trigger: 'hover', 'placement': 'right'  });
        });
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>
<div> <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right? <br /> Read More...">Hover over me</a> </div>
```

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I would try to modify it by adding the `manual` trigger and adding your own js. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'right'
    }).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).popover('show');
        $(".popover").mouseenter(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another solution

+1 to CodeGodie for his solution. I thought I would also include a detailed breakdown of what is going on within the site that you linked. Below is a simplified version of their code, and I included comments for each line so that you can follow along.

First, here is the JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/69k2kjng/36/

---

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var hideInfoLayerTimer, // create timer for hiding the info-layer
        showInfoLayerTimer, // create timer for showing the info-layer
        infoLayer = $('#infoLayer'); // set info-layer to variable

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // Bind the mouse events to the movie container, ...
    //  and also to any children of the movie container.
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    $('.movie').add('.movie span').on('mouseover',function(e){
        showInfoLayer(e.target); // begin the countdown to show the info-layer when the user's cursor hovers over the movie container (or children of the movie container)
    })
    .on('mouseout',function(e){
        hideInfoLayer(); // begin the countdown to hide the info-layer if the user's cursor leaves the movie-container
    });

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // Bind mouse events to the info-layer container
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    infoLayer.on('mouseover',function(e){ // reset the timer as the user's cursor hovers over the info-layer
        clearInterval(hideInfoLayerTimer);
    })
    .on('mouseout',function(e){ // begin the hide countdown if the user's cursor leaves the info-layer
        hideInfoLayer();
    });

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // create the function that sets the "showInfoLayerTimer"
    // -------------------------------------------------------    
    function showInfoLayer(obj){
        clearInterval(showInfoLayerTimer);
        clearInterval(hideInfoLayerTimer);
        // assign the movie container to a variable. also, double-check that it is the
        //  movie container and not a child of the movie container.
        var movie = $(obj).hasClass('movie') ? $(obj) : $(obj).parents('.movie');
        // when the user's cursor hovers over the movie container for 
        // longer than .5 seconds, this will display the info-layer
        showInfoLayerTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            clearInterval(showInfoLayerTimer)

            var title = movie.children('.movie-item-title').text(), // get the title text from the movie container
                info = movie.children('.movie-item-info').text(), // get the info text from the hidden child of the movie container.
                leftPos = movie[0].offsetLeft, // get the left offset of the movie container
                topPos = movie[0].offsetTop, // get the right offset of the movie container
                osWidth = movie[0].offsetWidth; // get the width of the movie container

            // here, we will position the info-layer prior to displaying it.
            infoLayer.css('top', topPos) // offset the top of the info-layer
            .css('left',leftPos+osWidth-10); // offset the left side of the info layer. 
            // **Note: Most tooltip plugins check which side of the element has more screen-space, and
            //    will alternate to align the right of the tooltip to the left of the element or vice-versa.
            infoLayer.children('.infolayer-item-title').text(title); // set the text of the info-layer "title" container
            infoLayer.children('.infolayer-item-info').text(info); // set the text of the info-layer "info" container

            infoLayer.fadeIn('fast'); // show the info-layer

        },500);
    };

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // create the function that sets the hideInfoLayerTimer
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    function hideInfoLayer(){
        clearInterval(showInfoLayerTimer); // clear any existing showInfoLayerTimers
        clearInterval(hideInfoLayerTimer); // clear any existing hideInfoLayerTimers

        hideInfoLayerTimer = setTimeout(function(){ // hide the info-layer if the user leaves the area for .1 seconds
            infoLayer.fadeOut('fast');
        },100);
    };

});
```

---

### HTML

```
<div data-movieid="1" class="movie">
<span class="movie-item-title">Lord of The Rings</span>
    <span class="movie-item-info" style="display:none;">
        A bunch of straight men fight over jewelry.
    </span>
</div>

<div data-movieid="2" class="movie">
    <span class="movie-item-title">Willy Wonka</span>
    <span class="movie-item-info" style="display:none;">
        An eccentric billionaire lures kids to his factory.
    </span>
</div>

<div id="infoLayer">
    <span class="infolayer-item-title"></span>
    <hr />
    <span class="infolayer-item-info" style="font-style:italic;color:grey;font-size:.9em;text-align:center;width:100%;display:block;"></span>
</div>
```

---

### CSS

```
.movie {
    float: left;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #4072B4;
    border: solid 1px black;
    color:white;
    width: 165px;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 220px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.movie .movie-item-title {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 50% auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#infoLayer {
    color: grey;
    height: 100px;
    width: 272px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: none;
    top: 38px;
    left: 378px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.97);
}    

#infoLayer .infolayer-item-title {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.2em;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and great breakdown!

Comment: @HessamMT You're certainly welcome, sir! Feel free to mark my answer as correct, and/or up-vote it if I helped.